# Problema con las medallas ganadas por etiqueta

Tags: soporte, medallas-de-etiqueta

Con la ayuda de @rnrneverdies me he dado cuenta de que las medallas que son otorgadas por etiqueta al parecer no están funcionando, de acuerdo a la entrada sobre [Medallas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) en el Centro de Ayuda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya hace algún tiempo que he pasado los 100 puntos de reputación para el tag [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) y estoy seguro que más de 20 de mis respuestas no son wikis:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Ayuda?

Comment: esta raro esto permíteme investigar.

Comment: @JuanM gracias!

Comment: relacionada http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/413/25

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No es un fallo del sistema. El problema es que aún no ha habido suficientes preguntas sobre [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

Si vas a la [descripción de la etiqueta en el meta de StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68395) (por cierto, una [muy buena pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) sobre las medallas en la red de SE), puedes ver las condiciones completas para obtener cada medalla, incluyendo detalles que no vienen en la descripción básica.

Entonces, para obtener la medalla de etiqueta se tienen que cumplir estos requisitos:

- Obtener más de 100 puntos (para bronce)
- Sólo cuentan respuestas no borradas que no sean wikis de comunidad.
- El usuario debe haber respondido al menos 20 veces en esa etiqueta.
- La etiqueta debe tener al menos 100 preguntas.

Como usuario, cumples todos los requisitos para obtener la medalla de Python; el problema es que Python ahora mismo sólo tiene 93 preguntas en SOes y no se otorgarán medallas de etiqueta hasta que alcance 100. En cuanto se alcance ese número y corra el proceso que otorga las medallas (sobre las 3AM UTC [como indica rnrneverdies en los comentarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/443/problema-con-las-medallas-ganadas-por-etiqueta/447?noredirect=1#comment1054_447)) deberías recibir la medalla automáticamente.

Comment: Gracias Álvaro, era la pieza que faltaba en el rompecabezas

Comment: muy buena, esto lo explica todo.

Comment: excelente respuesta!! no entendía porque no aparecían etiquetas donde tenía respuestas.

Comment: Por cierto @César no recibirá la medalla automáticamente cuando `python` alcance las 100 preguntas, sino la proxima vez que se ejecute el proceso que las otorga, que se ejecuta todos los días a las 3AM UTC (aprox).

Comment: @rnrneverdies está técnicamente en lo correcto (lo más correcto que hay). César tendrá que esperar a que corra el proceso que la otorga, pero no tendrá que realizar ninguna acción (aparte de esperar).

Comment: entiendo, lo dije para que redondees la rta. saludos.

Comment: Mi referencia a Futurama pasó desapercibida :-P

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro jajaja yo si decía que había escuchado eso en algún lado

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Interesante saber que se tienen que tener 100 ó más preguntas para adjudicarse una medalla! Gracias.